# How to avoid blind update in jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi if i use merge for updating a record  the hibernate query generated will have all the columns even though i'm setting single property/column . is there any solution to avoid this blind update ?? only setting columns have to come in hibernate query.

Comment: `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();`

Comment: I don't really see how this is a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is the Hibernate specific (non-JPA compliant) dynamic-update attribute.

There is some discussion of the issue here:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Note however that as the Hibernate specific `@Entity` annotation has been deprecated in versions 4+, rather than the solution outlined in the above you should use the `@DynamicUpdate` annotation if you are using Hibernate 4+:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class MyEntity{

}
```